# My Ubuntu 18.04 chroot doesn't link /bin to /usr/bin

Tags: 18.04, root, symbolic-link, chroot

So my Ubuntu 18.04 chroot was not linking `/bin` to `/usr/bin`. But my Ubuntu 19.04 chroot was linking `/bin` to `/usr/bin`.

```bsh
root@localhost:/# ls
bin   data  etc   lib    mnt  proc  run   sdcard  sys  usr      boot  dev   home  media  opt  root  sbin  srv     tmp  var
root@localhost:/# ll                                            
total 88
drwx------.  22 root root 4096 Sep  8 10:00 ./                  drwx------.  22 root root 4096 Sep  8 10:00 ../
drwx------.   2 root root 8192 Sep 10 18:17 bin/                drwx------.   2 root root 4096 Apr 24  2018 boot/
drwx------.   3 root root 4096 Sep  8 10:00 data/
drwxr-xr-x.  14 root root 4840 Sep 12 05:44 dev/                drwx------. 101 root root 4096 Sep 12 16:54 etc/
drwx------.   5 root root 4096 Sep  8 09:35 home/
drwx------.  10 root root 4096 Sep 12 16:53 lib/                drwx------.   2 root root 4096 Jul 14 10:58 media/
drwx------.   2 root root 4096 Jul 14 10:58 mnt/                drwx------.   2 root root 4096 Jul 14 10:58 opt/
dr-xr-xr-x. 323 root root    0 Jan  1  1970 proc/               drwxrwxr--.  28 root root 4096 Sep 12 17:13 root/
drwx------.  11 root root 4096 Sep 12 16:53 run/                drwx------.   2 root root 8192 Sep 12 16:53 sbin/
drwxrwx--x.  42 root 1028 4096 Sep  9 09:51 sdcard/             drwx------.   2 root root 4096 Jul 14 10:58 srv/
drwx------.   2 root root 4096 Apr 24  2018 sys/                drwx------.   9 root root 4096 Sep 12 17:33 tmp/
drwx------.  10 root root 4096 Jul 14 10:58 usr/                drwx------.  12 root root 4096 Sep  7 23:25 var/
root@localhost:/#
```

Because it, i copy all binary commands from  `/bin` to `/usr/bin`. And i linking the directory, but i get this message:

```bsh
root@localhost:/# ln /usr/bin -fds /
ln: /bin: cannot overwrite directory
root@localhost:/# ln /usr/bin -fds /
ln: /bin: cannot overwrite directory
root@localhost:/# ln /usr/bin -fd /
ln: /bin: cannot overwrite directory                            root@localhost:/# ln /usr/bin -d /
ln: failed to create hard link '/bin' => '/usr/bin': Operation not permitted
root@localhost:/# ln /usr/bin -ds /                             ln: failed to create symbolic link '/bin': File exists
root@localhost:/# ln /usr/bin/ -ds /
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/bin': File exists          root@localhost:/#
```

Please an trick for linking `/bin` to `/usr/bin`..

Comment: Why would you want to link `/bin` to `/usr/bin`?

Comment: @vidarlo, yes i want link `/bin` to `/usr/bin`

Comment: But why would you want to do this? What do you want to achieve?